# Drawing Lines in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, lines

I am a C# newbie and have encountered a problem in my homework.

I have a panel in 'Form1.cs' called panel3.

Now, I have a class called 'Staff' and I want to add a method in Staff to draw a sequence of lines underneath each other.  These lines must be added and shown in panel3 (found in Form1.cs).

How can I do this please?  Thank you.

I have something like this in the "Staff.cs":

My problem is how I am going to invoke it in Form1_Load event?  What parameters should I pass to it?

I want the 'Draw' method to draw the lines in panel3 found in 'Form1.cs'.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Thanks a lot for your help :)  I have solved it now thanks to you :)

Comment: could you include some **relevant** code?

Comment: Show your code and tell us where you stuck.

Comment: Does your class `Staff` class implement a Control?

Comment: aren't C# global variables distributed along all the files in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Override OnPaint event in your Staff class
2. Create staffIndex propertie - then you can edit it directly in Properties window
3. Compile project - Staff control apears in Tool box
4. Drag and Drop your Staff control on your Form.

---

```
public class Staff : Panel
{
    public const int kOffset = 30;
    public const int kSignatureOffset = 25;
    public const int kStaffSpacing = 70;
    public const int kBarSpacing = 7;
    const int kNumMeasuresOnAStaff = 4;
    public const int kStaffInPixels = 800;

    public int staffIndex { get; set; }

    public Staff()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int yPos = kOffset + staffIndex * kStaffSpacing;
        for (int bars = 0; bars < 5; bars++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, yPos, kStaffInPixels, yPos);
            yPos += kBarSpacing;
        }
    }
}
```